# GAE success from cli, failure from Cloud Build. Error:not found

Tags: maven, google-app-engine, gcloud, google-cloud-build

I have a Java App that deploys to Google App Engine and works when deploying from the commandline. The build shows all green when I run it from Cloud Build. When I hit the URL, I get a message Error: Not Found. Note that I have replaced the name of my GAE project and service name that runs in it for this post.

Here are the commands as I run them from a shell:

```
git clone git@github.com:johncrider/MyProj
cd MyProj/
/Applications/apache-maven-3.6.0/bin/mvn clean package
gcloud app deploy src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml
```

Here is the contents of cloudbuild.yaml that gives me green lights in Cloud Build:

```
steps:
# Decrypt the file containing the key
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
  args:
  - kms
  - decrypt
  - --ciphertext-file=id_rsa.enc
  - --plaintext-file=/root/.ssh/id_rsa
  - --location=global
  - --keyring=my-keyring
  - --key=github-key
  volumes:
  - name: 'ssh'
    path: /root/.ssh
# Set up git with key and domain.
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/git'
  entrypoint: 'bash'
  args:
  - '-c'
  - |
    chmod 600 /root/.ssh/id_rsa
    cat <<EOF >/root/.ssh/config
    Hostname github.com
    IdentityFile /root/.ssh/id_rsa
    EOF
    mv known_hosts /root/.ssh/known_hosts
  volumes:
  - name: 'ssh'
    path: /root/.ssh
# Use git clone.
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/git'
  args:
  - clone
  - git@github.com:johncrider/MyProj
  volumes:
  - name: 'ssh'
    path: /root/.ssh
# set default project
- name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud"
  args: ["config", "set", "project", "GAEProject"]
# build maven package
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/mvn'
  args: ['clean', 'package', '-DskipTests']
  volumes:
  - name: 'ssh'
    path: /root/.ssh
#Deploy to GAE
- name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud"
  args: ["app", "deploy", "src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml"]
  volumes:
  - name: 'ssh'
    path: /root/.ssh
timeout: "1600s"
```

The last step is Step 5. Here is the results of that step from the Cloud Build Logs.

```
Starting Step #5
Step #5: Already have image (with digest): gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud
Step #5: Services to deploy:
Step #5: 
Step #5: descriptor:      [/workspace/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml]
Step #5: source:          [/workspace/src/main/webapp]
Step #5: target project:  [gaeproject]
Step #5: target service:  [myproject]
Step #5: target version:  [20190110t151311]
Step #5: target url:      [https://myproject-dot-gaeproject.appspot.com]
Step #5: 
Step #5: 
Step #5: Do you want to continue (Y/n)?  
Step #5: Beginning deployment of service [myproject]...
Step #5: #============================================================#
Step #5: #= Uploading 0 files to Google Cloud Storage                =#
Step #5: #============================================================#
Step #5: File upload done.
Step #5: Updating service [myproject]...
Step #5: ............................................................done.
Step #5: Setting traffic split for service [myproject]...
Step #5: .............done.
Step #5: Deployed service [myproject] to [https://myproject-dot-gaeproject.appspot.com]
Step #5: 
Step #5: You can stream logs from the command line by running:
Step #5:   $ gcloud app logs tail -s myproject
Step #5: 
Step #5: To view your application in the web browser run:
Step #5:   $ gcloud app browse -s myproject
Finished Step #5
```

The log entry when the service starts does not show any errors.

Comment: Which URL are you hitting? What do you see for that particular request in the developer console [logs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/writing-application-logs#viewing_application_logs)?

Comment: The error when hitting the deployed web service is a 404 - No handlers matched this URL.

I use the URL from the message: https://myproject-dot-gaeproject.appspot.com

When I use the same deploy command from the Cloud Console, the service works fine.